# Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating , Binary XML file line #7<gradient> tag requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45

Tags: java, android, gradle, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

I wrote a android game power by **recycle view**  called **word game master**
After running and building, the program crashes.
4 types of exceptions were `thrown`.

1.`android.view.InflateException`,
2.`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`,
3.`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`,
4.`XmlPullParserException`

What's the matter?

A part of the program sources that I think is involved with exceptions:

1. `item_level.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.ss.wordgame.SquareFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_rv_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_level_num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textSize="42sp"
            tools:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="مرحله" />

    </LinearLayout>
</com.ss.wordgame.SquareFrameLayout>
```

2.`background_rv_item.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#3E4458"
        android:angle="100"
        android:endColor="#333746">

    </gradient>


    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

3.`SquareFrameLayout.java` file

```
package com.ss.wordgame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class SquareFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

4.`LevelAdapter.java` file

```
package com.ss.wordgame;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LevelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LevelAdapter.LevelViewHolder> {
    private List<Level> levels = new ArrayList<>();
    private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<Level> onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;


    public LevelAdapter(List<Level> levels, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<Level> onRecyclerViewItemClickListener) {
        this.levels = levels;
        this.onRecyclerViewItemClickListener = onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public LevelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new LevelViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_level, parent, false
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LevelViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindLevel(levels.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return levels.size();
    }

    public class LevelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;

        public LevelViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_level_num);
        }

        public void bindLevel(final Level level) {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(level.getId()));
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onRecyclerViewItemClickListener.onItemClick(level, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

out put `Stack Trace Exception`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ss.wordgame, PID: 4438

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.ss.wordgame.SquareFrameLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.ss.wordgame.SquareFrameLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at com.ss.wordgame.LevelAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(LevelAdapter.java:27)
    at com.ss.wordgame.LevelAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(LevelAdapter.java:14)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:557)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.ss.wordgame:drawable/background_rv_item with resource ID #0x7f07005f
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_rv_item.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07005f

    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4175)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:92)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:87)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:82)
    at com.ss.wordgame.SquareFrameLayout.<init>(SquareFrameLayout.java:18)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at com.ss.wordgame.LevelAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(LevelAdapter.java:27)
    at com.ss.wordgame.LevelAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(LevelAdapter.java:14)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:557)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #7<gradient> tag requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45

    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.updateGradientDrawableGradient(GradientDrawable.java:1544)
    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflateChildElements(GradientDrawable.java:1366)
    at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:1187)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
    ... 78 more
```

And the output I expected:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckkr5.png)

Comment: The error says "Binary XML file line #7<gradient> tag requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45", but you're using 100. Does it work if you use a multiple of 45?

Comment: thank you ianhanniballake – 
The problem was solved